# Hot-wiring/bootstrapping jQuery's constructor

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to hot-wire (or bootstrap, if you will) jQuery's constructor, in order to implement functionality in-front of it's default functionality. For instance; say I want to implement automatic caching...

*Peudo-code alert!*

```
var _init = $.init;

var cache = [];

// override jQuery's init function (the function that gets executed when
// you query the DOM
$.init.prototype = function (selector, context, rootjQuery)
{
    // if whatever selector is run, is not in the cache; cache it, using
    // the "old" init function
    if (!cache[selector]) cache[selector] = _init(selector, context, rootjQuery);

    // return cached instance
    return cache[selector];
}
```

I know that this will break on elements that are updated dynamically and what not. The aim here is a crude implementation, which is going to be locked away in a dark corner somewhere. I also acknowledge that this is against all common sense. But humour me :)

Comment: What do you mean "hot wire" the constructor?  Do you mean something other than just writing a plugin? http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html  As with all javascript, you can overwrite or add whatever you want wherever you want... The issue is whether the framework will place nice.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [`jQuery.sub()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/).

It allows to make a new copy of jQuery and overwrite those methods and properties without breaking the global jQuery.

If you must you can inject this subclass of jQuery back into global scope.

```
(function() {
    var $$ = jQuery.sub();

    $$.fn.init = function() {

        var obj = $.apply(null, arguments);
        console.log("object: ", obj);
        return obj;
    };

    $$(function() {
        // do stuff with overwritten jQuery.
        $$("div");
    });

})();
```

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/tvmdp/23/).

It's best to just make a factory that returns jQuery objects since jQuery has too many closures going on and you really need to know exactly what's going on or it will break.

The second object logged is indeed the document and thats from the `$$(f)` call since the selector becomes the document when you use jQuery as a ready handler.

Comment: -1 Have you even tested this? Has the up-voters even tested this?

Comment: @roosteronacid it's pseudo code. Not fully working code. Of course it doesn't work because I have `...` everywhere and that's not valid syntax.

Comment: @Ryanos: I am looking for working code. Even with your code sanitized, it still fails.

Comment: I was a bit too quick on the keyboard just there. "Fails" was a bit too strong... It works fine, but you don't have access to the result of the query. Sure; you can console.log() stuff, but without access to the query-result (being able to modify the result before returning it, or returning something else), you can't do much

Comment: Then apply it first modify it and then return it. The order doesnt really matter. as long as you know what your doing and dont break the jquery api

Comment: After applying `old`, it refers to document on any query on `$$`. Can you elaborate. I must be missing something.

Comment: @roosteronacid this is really unstable. I recommend you do not hook into jQuery like this but instead create a factory.

Comment: @roosteronacid overwriting $.fn.init has all kinds of horrible side effects. Returning a new jQuery object is save though.